# UILabel showing wrong Values in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am using Coredata and NSFetchedResultsController to store and retrieve Values and show them in a table view.I am creating a custom label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and displaying the value of an attribute 'lastname'. But I am getting wrong values.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *label = nil;
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    label = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,10,120,21)]autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    //Configure the cell
    List *list = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    label.text = list.lastname;

}
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
return cell;
}
```

the wierd part is that it is working fine if i remove the `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` line and the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move

```
label.text = list.lastname;
```

outside of the

```
if(cell == nil)
```

The reason is, that the content inside of the `if(cell == nil)` will get called only x times, where x is the number of visible cells on the screen. As you scroll, the new cells are being reused and that's why they contain some incorrect value.

EDIT:

You will also need to move your

```
List *list = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

outside of the `if`.

EDIT 2:

This is how it should look like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *label = nil;
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    label = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,10,120,21)]autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.tag=1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];


}
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

//Configure the cell
List *list = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
label.text = list.lastname;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
return cell;
}
```

this should work for you

Comment: put it after your `[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Take a look at EDIT 2 - this is how you should implement your function. The Label is added to your cell with a Tag - with this tag you can access this label outside of your `if()` and set the correct value